# Generating a power series around a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$ with $y(0)=-2, y'(0)=6$ which I need to turn into a power series. Here's what I have so far but I'm getting stuck rather early.

I turn it into $y''-{x\over(x-1)}y' + {1\over(x-1)}y = 0$ how do I finish this from here. I keep trying to solve it but end up getting bogged down in the algebra.

Comment: It's easier to leave the equation in its original form to use the series solutions then you don't have to divide

Answer (score 0):

For: $(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$ with $y(0)=-2, y'(0)=6$, then use 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^{n}$$
which leads to
\begin{align}
x \, f'(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \, a_{n} \, x^{n} \\
f''(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} \, x^{n} \\
x \, f''(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n+1) \, a_{n+1} \, x^{n}.
\end{align}
The equation can now take the form
$$0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-(n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} + n(n+1) \, a_{n+1} - n \, a_{n} + a_{n}) \, x^{n}$$
Equating coefficients leads to the equation, with $a_{0} = -2$ and $a_{1} = 6$,
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1) \, a_{n+1} - (n-1) \, a_{n}}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$
Calculating a few terms provides 
$$a_{n} = \frac{a_{0}}{n!}$$
for $n \geq 2$.

Placing all the parts together provides one solution as
$$f(x) = 2 \, ( 4 \, x - e^{x}).$$